# Ruby gsub check or (||) pattern

Tags: ruby

Ruby Experts,

I'm trying to check and remove string from multiple files under a folder and below is my code snippet,

```
........
work_files = Dir.glob("E:\nano\*_access.txt")

val=File.open('E\new_dir\access_list.txt').read
val.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    work_files.each do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      new_content = text.gsub(( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '')  || ( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\n/, '' )) 
..........
........
```

from one of the files,like below I'm checking for the string **ncr\atxe5t** (can occur multiple times also). its getting removed from the last line for the pattern (/#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '') but its not getting removed from the last but one line for the pattern - /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\n/, '' .

I;m getting the error like below

> ...                               ^ test.rb:14: syntax error,
>   unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...| ( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\n/, '' ))

Eg. E:\nano\ids_access.txt

```
# Digital created on July 2016
# Digital Owner: John Cena (jxcgo)
# Digital access: create delete access

[pool]
@rem = ncr\abc_efg_dev, ncr\abc_efg_test, ncr\jx8go5, ncr\atxe5t
@digital_owner = ncr\atxe5t, ncr\yui30n, ncr\bhyrl4
```

I'm not sure whether or (||) condition pattern is allowed in gsub method but I want to make use of the gsub method only. is it possible in ruby. Thanks in advance. Hope I have explained clearly.

Comment: I have added one more gsub and it worked

     `new_content = text.gsub(( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' ) `

but I cant remove the comma from the last word of a line:

`@rem = ncr\abc_efg_dev, ncr\abc_efg_test, ncr\jx8go5,`

want to remove the comma after ncr\jx8go5 . not sure how to .

Answer (score 1):

Nope, `||` is not usable in method args. I think that's what you want to do:
`gsub(/#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,(\s|\Z)/, '')`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan , I've tried using `new_content = text.gsub(( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' )`

but I cant remove the comma from the last word of a line: `@rem = ncr\abc_efg_dev, ncr\abc_efg_test, ncr\jx8go5,` want to remove the comma after ncr\jx8go5 . not sure how to

I suppose your answer doesn't intend to delete the final comma after deletion.

Comment: Please try this: `new_content = text.gsub(( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\Z/, '' )` or `gsub(/#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,(\s|\Z)/, '')` which should be the same

Comment: Thanks again Ivan for your time. I tried yours and it didn't match the string occurring at end of line. Mine is removing the last string match (ncr\atxe5t) but its not removing the comma after the string - ncr\jx8go5,

my regex

`new_content = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' )`

I tried to remove the comma of ncr\jx8go5, by using below regex but no luck.

`new_content = = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' ).gsub(/\,$/, '')`